# pass 2 parameters and update a table based on the value from 2 tables that are related

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Microsoft sql 2008

This three tables below are related joined by b=b  and d=d 
I want to query the 3 tables and update the value in table 2 column3=d by using a declare set column1=a in table1 and also declare set column2=f in table3 .Once the condition is met update table 2 column3 with the value from table3 column3

```
table 1
column1 column2 column3
  a         b        c

table 2
column1 column2 column3
 c        b      d

table 3
column1 column2 column3
e       f        d
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE table2 t2
  INNER JOIN table1 t1 ON t1.column2=t2.column2
  INNER JOIN table3 t3 ON t3.column3=t2.column3
SET t2.column3=t3.column3
WHERE t1.column1='a'
  AND t2.column2='f'
```

Like this?

Comment: One other question can I use a declare valuable at the top and initialize the values as nvarchar and get them passed instead ?

Comment: Please accept the answer as correct. See http://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/declare_vars.php how to declare variables